# AJAX response using Jquery (with zend framework) contains unwanted HTML Code

Tags: json, zend-framework, jquery

Currently, the following code works as intended but if I add an echo such as "LANG: en" anywhere in the code (let's say in the bootstrap), the following code won't work anymore and I get this ajax request response :

```
<br/>LANG : en{"response":true,"id":13}
```

(the ajax response contains the echo + json array ) and therefore I'm not able to print the id (it will print : undefined when i will try to access to data.id).

**My question is : How can I print my debug info and still manage to perform ajax requests ?**

Here is my code in the controller :

```
public function init()
{
$this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('retrievecategories', 'json')->initContext();
}

public function retrievecategoriesAction()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); 
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if (isset($_POST['id']))
         $id = $_POST['id'];
        $id+=1;
        echo json_encode(array('response' => true, 'id' => $id));
        }
    }
```

My js code :

```
jQuery(function(){

var obj = {"id":12};

jQuery.ajax({
url: '/search/retrievecategories?json',
type: 'post',
data: obj,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
var id = data.id;
alert(id);
},
error: function(data){
var id = data.id;
alert(id);
}
});
```

});

I hope I was clear enough. Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you echo anything but the JSON object, the JQuery parser will fail because the response is no longer a valid JSON. you could make a custom parser which interprets the response text and takes away the debug info leaving the JSON object, or you can include the debug info in the array you encode.

```
json_encode(array('data'=>'data','debug'=>'debug info'))
```

Then you detect if the debug field is present and after a console.log() or alert() you delete it form the object.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend that you read about [firePHP](http://www.firephp.org).  It uses the same console that Firebug uses to display debug information from your php code.  It is really simple to use with the Zend_Log.